# How to change the datetime format in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, datetime

I have a list of dictionaries as below,

```
[{'Name':'Henry','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0),'End Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 0, 0)},
{'Name':'Zack','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0), 'End Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 0, 0)},
{'Name':'Stuart','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0),'End Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 0, 0)}]
```

How to transform my date format to given output?

```
[{'Name':'Henry','Start Date': '05-12-2018  12:00:00 AM','End Date': '10-04-2020  12:00:00 AM'},
{'Name':'Zack','Start Date': '05-12-2018  12:00:00 AM','End Date': '07-12-2018  12:00:00 AM',
{'Name':'Stuart','Start Date': '05-12-2018  12:00:00 AM','End Date': '10-04-2020  12:00:00 AM'}]
```

This is a test data original data has more records. This record is dynamic so need a generic solution. It's not necessary that the datetime key have same name every time.

Comment: have you read the documentation of `datetime`?

Comment: There is something called `.strptime` in the datetime module

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah I have. I made some changes in question. have a look at it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strftime` from `datetime` to convert to your desired format (`%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p`).

```py
import datetime

dates = [{'Name':'Henry','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0),'End Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 0, 0)},
{'Name':'Zack','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0), 'End Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 0, 0)},
{'Name':'Stuart','Start Date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0),'End Date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 0, 0)}]


for date in dates:
    start_date = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(date["Start Date"], "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
    end_date = str(datetime.datetime.strftime(date["End Date"], "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

    date["Start Date"] = start_date
    date["End Date"] = end_date


print(dates)
```

##### Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Henry', 'Start Date': '05-12-2018 12:00:00 AM', 'End Date': '10-04-2020 12:00:00 AM'}, {'Name': 'Zack', 'Start Date': '05-12-2018 12:00:00 AM', 'End Date': '07-12-2018 12:00:00 AM'}, {'Name': 'Stuart', 'Start Date': '05-12-2018 12:00:00 AM', 'End Date': '10-04-2020 12:00:00 AM'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

'''
from datetime import datetime

((datetime(2018, 12, 5, 0, 0)).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
'''

Use this format